# iPhone - Is it possible to have two videos to be played simulataniously

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've having video being played and on the top of it, i'm having a button. The video player view size is 480 pixels width and 320 pixels height.
On click of it I want to play another video as "inset". This video size will be 48 pixels wide and 32 pixels height.

Is it possible to play two videos like that?
Will apple accept such kind of videos?

Comment: check this lint it may help u http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2010/12/playing-movies-or-videos-in-queue-using.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can play two videos at a time by using two `AVplayer` or 1 `MPMoviePlayerControllers` and `1 AVplayer`.
Hope this will help

Comment: Even more there is no restriction on the amount of `AVPlayer`'s in use.

Comment: This is the valid solution when the question is answered and so i accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot play two videos at a time.